# How do I get SonarQube and Emma unit test coverage with Jacoco IT code coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, emma, jacoco

I'm trying to get Sonar IT Code coverage to work for me when my unit tests are "covered" via Emma.

My situation :

(1) I have unit tests that make extensive use of JMockit.  Removing JMockit is not an option.  I want to get unit test coverage reports for these tests.

(2) I have integration tests that simply run the core server side portion of the app (its a Spring web app) with different input scenarios.   I want IT code coverage reports for this.

For part (1) I have chosen to use Emma for my unit test coverage mainly because I was having issues with Jacoco and JMockit working together due to both tangling each other up while instrumenting the java classes on the fly.  There are some issues with these tools working together - with no solution that I saw as being reliable and non-invasive to the unit tests themselves.  So in the end, I chose to use Emma as its does "offline instrumentation" to perform the code coverage.   Jacoco does offline as well, but I could not get Sonar to pick up its results in this mode (Maybe I forgot a semi-colon :-) ).

For part (2) [ *the IT code coverage part* ] I have only seen the ability to specify the following property

```
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/coverage/jacoco.exec
```

I can only assume, we need to use Jacoco to instrument the IT tests?  Correct me if I'm wrong.  So technically I can use Jacoco for this part of the tests because my integration tests do not use JMockit.

This is what I did.  I have a separate ant task that recompiles the code base (stripping out the Emma instrumentation) and then repackages the application and runs the jacoco:coverage tool against my integration tests.

Problem is.. my unit tests are Emma based.. so how do you tell Sonar to use the Emma plugin for the Emma unit tests and the Jacoco plugin for the IT tests?  Can this even be done?

Here is how I set up my Sonar properties:

```
sonar.test=test

sonar.sources=src

sonar.binaries=build/compile

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=emma
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=emma
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/coverage/jacoco.exec
sonar.emma.reportPath=build/coverage
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test/report
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=build/test/report
```

My ant build runs the Emma unit tests (output in Emma form) and then the IT tests are run with the output to the jacoco.exec file.  Then I upload to Sonar.

I get the unit test coverage stats - not the IT stats.   I'm not really surprised with the results.

But does anyone have an idea where I made a wrong turn?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  In the end what I did was remove some of my crashing jmockit tests that were causing issues and re-implemented them in a different fashion.  Note.  Some of my jmockit unit tests would work and others would not.  I could never divine a pattern as to what in jmockit was giving jacoco its issues.

Answer (score 0):

You already made some efforts using jacoco for your unit-test-coverage. I would continue trying to make that solution work and maybe post your difficulties with that here.

I recommend to try using jacoco for both coverage reports, because Integration-Coverage can only be analysed with jacoco, as you can read here:

http://www.sonarqube.org/measure-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar-updated/

I have consulted the documentation of sonarqube and configuration-websites and did not find a possibility to use different coverage plugins.

You can find the documentation for 
Unit-Test-Coverage here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project

and for Int-Test-Coverage here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project